# selenium run chrome on raspberry pi

Tags: python, selenium, raspberry-pi

If your seeing this I guess you are looking to run chromium on a raspberry pi with selenium.

like this `Driver = webdriver.Chrome("path/to/chomedriver")` or like this `webdriver.Chrome()`

Answer (score 5):

I have concluded, after hours and a whole night of debugging that you can't install it, because there is no chromedriver compatible with a raspberry pi processor. Even if you download the linux 32bit. You can confirm it by running this line in a terminal window `path/to/chromedriver` it will give you this error

> cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Hope this helps anyone that wanted to do this :)

Comment: Have you tried to run Selenium with Firefox on Ubuntu Core 18 with Raspberry Pi?